Is there a method from any lottie player libraries to validate the lottie JSON file
I would like the users to upload Lottie JSON. But, before they could upload the file, I would like to validate if it's a valid Lottie JSON. Is there any method to do so with the exitsing lottie player library or would I have to write it myself based on their docs?
I tried the Lottie Player which crashes abrupty when we pass an incorrect JSON. But, it's the component that crashes. I am looking for a method from the library itself than trying some work around to verify if the component crashes.
